# Printing Min1 and Min2 using Python

Tags: python, list, iterator, min

What am I missing in this code here so that it sets min1 and min2 to the two smallest numbers?

```
def test() : # do not change this line!
  list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] # do not change this line!          
  min1 = list[0]
  min2 = list[1]
  #missing code here
  print(min1, min2)
  return (min1, min2) # do not change this line!
  # do not write any code below here  
test() # do not change this line!
  # do not remove this line!
```

Comment: 1. You are using 'list' as a variable name but its a keyword. 2. there is no logic implemented to fetch the min values anywhere. 3. returned value is not getting assigned anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List does not sort elements in it implicitly. You have sort the list with sort() function. So before you take min1 and min2 from list you have sort list using sort function, you can do that with *nameofyourlist*.sort() and also you are not assigning return value of test() to any variable so you can avoid that line. Your final code can be as below

```
def test():
    list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5]
    list.sort()
    min1 = list[0]
    min2 = list[1]
    print(min1, min2)

test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just insert

```
list = sorted(list)
```

after this line

```
list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] # do not change this line!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the line `list.sort()` to sort the list into ascending order, then your code will return the two smallest values.

```
def test() : # do not change this line!
  list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] # do not change this line!
  list.sort()
  min1 = list[0]
  min2 = list[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that there will be more than one value in the `list` then you can sort the list and assign first two items in `min1` and `min2`.

```
def test() : # do not change this line!
  list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] # do not change this line!
  list = sorted(list)
  min1 = list[0]
  min2 = list[1]
  #missing code here

  print(min1, min2)
  return (min1, min2) # do not change this line!
# do not write any code below here  

test() # do not change this line!
# do not remove this line!
```

Output:

```
-5 -2
```

**Update**

Updated the code. As we can't change the line with `list` declaration we can store the sorted list in next line and then assign first two values in two variables.

Comment: Updated the answer. As there is a comment `list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] # do not change this line!` we can't apply sorted method in the declaration. Thank you finding that I was sorting twice.