# Can we use python keywords as variable names without explicitly overriding?

Tags: python

I searched for similar questions and the closest I could find is this: [how-do-i-use-a-keyword-as-a-variable-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968516/how-do-i-use-a-keyword-as-a-variable-name)

One of the answers to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043953/printing-min1-and-min2-using-python#62043953), uses 'list' keyword as a variable name and it is working fine.

```
def test() : # do not change this line!
  list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] # do not change this line!
  list = sorted(list)
  min1 = list[0]
  min2 = list[1]
  #missing code here

  print(min1, min2)
  return (min1, min2) # do not change this line!
# do not write any code below here  

test() # do not change this line!
# do not remove this line!
```

Output:

```
-5 -2
```

My understanding was that we cannot use python keywords as variable names. Is there any special scenario where is works? Many thanks for your help.

Update:

As suggested in one of the comments, some built-in types are allowed to be used as variables. I ended up testing them [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html):

```
# and = 1;
# print(and) # does not work

# or = 1;
# print(or) # does not work

# not = 1;
# print(not) # does not work

# int = 1;
# print(int) # works

# float = 1;
# print(float) # works

# complex = 1;
# print(complex) # works

# list = 1;
# print(list) # works

# tuple = 1;
# print(tuple) # works

# range = 1;
# print(range) # works

# str = 1;
# print(str) # works

# bytes = 1;
# print(bytes) # works

# bytearray = 1;
# print(bytearray) # works

# memoryview = 1;
# print(memoryview) # works

# print = 1;
# print(print) # does not work

# set = 1;
# print(set) # works

# frozenset = 1;
# print(frozenset) # works

# dict = 1;
# print(dict) # works
```

Information worth keeping a note of.

Comment: `list` isn't a **keyword** though... it's the name of a builtin type but it's not part of the *grammar* of the language. It's bad practice to *shadow* it but it's allowed... what the interpreter will baulk at is if you try "if = 3" or "else = 3" etc... where those are actually keywords.

Comment: I was not aware of that, worth exploring more. Thanks !

Comment: On a side note: The stdlib module [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/keyword.html) might be of interest

Answer (score 3):

Keywords[1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) are not the same as built-in functions[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs). You're able to use the latter as variables, but you should generally avoid such.